# if else and awk ... correction needed in my command

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files file1 is a query file and file2 is a kind of dictionary each of 1 column. I want to check if the element of file1 is present in file2 it should give 1 else 0 as an output.

This is what I am doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat file1 `
   do
     cat file2 | awk '{ if ($1=="'$i'") print 1 ; else 0 }'>>output
   done
```

Please give your suggestions to improve the commands

Thank you

Comment: Looks like grep would be a better fit than awk for this task. If you have `fgrep` available, this the exact sort of task for which it was designed.

Comment: would you mind giving a two line demo of it

Comment: can't you compare them two with `diff` ?

Comment: @Angelo: It looks like your entire script reduces to: `fgrep -f file1 file2 > output`. I should add that if you don't have fgrep available, `grep -F` is normally the same.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin neat trick I salute you, why don't you provide an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

Content of `file1`:

```
monday
tuesday
wednesday
thursday
friday
saturday
sunday
```

Content of `file2`:

```
tuesday
saturday
```

Execute next `awk` command:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { f2[ $1 ] = 1; next } FNR < NR { print (($1 in f2) ? 1 : 0) >"output" }' file2 file1
```

Content of `output`:

```
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your entire script reduces to:

```
fgrep -f file1 file2 > output
```

I should add that if you don't have fgrep available, `grep -F` is normally the same.

`fgrep` (or, usually, `grep -F`) is normally implemented with the Aho-Corisack string matching algorithm, so it's normally quite a bit faster than using `grep` repeatedly. The one thing to keep in mind (which isn't *entirely* clear here, but seems likely) is that the `f` in `fgrep` stands for `fixed` -- it matches any of a number of alternative fixed strings quickly, but it does *not* to REs at all -- each string is simply matched literally.

If you need RE matching, you can still use the `-f` option with grep, so you'd get:

```
grep -f file1 file2 > output
```